# float number to string converting implementation in STD

Tags: c++, floating-point, printf, std, floating-accuracy

I faced with a curious issue. Look at this simple code:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char buf[1000];
    snprintf_l(buf, sizeof(buf), _LIBCPP_GET_C_LOCALE, "%.17f", 0.123e30f);
    std::cout << "WTF?: " << buf << std::endl;
}
```

The output looks quire wired:

```
123000004117574256822262431744.00000000000000000
```

My question is how it's implemented? Can someone show me the original code? I did not find it. Or maybe it's too complicated for me.

I've tried to reimplement the same transformation double to string with Java code but was failed. Even when I tried to get exponent and fraction parts separately and summarize fractions in cycle I always get zeros instead of these numbers "...822262431744". When I tried to continue summarizing fractions after the 23 bits (for float number) I faced with other issue - how many fractions I need to collect? Why the original code stops on left part and does not continue until the scale is end?
So, I really do not understand the basic logic, how it implemented. I've tried to define really big numbers (e.g. 0.123e127f). And it generates huge number in decimal format. The number has much higher precision than float can be. Looks like this is an issue, because the string representation contains something which float number cannot.

Comment: Looks fine to me `0.123e30f` is a 30 digit number but `float` only has about 7 to 9 digits of precision so the rest are "invented". The format string `"%.17f"` specifies non-scientific notation with 17 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Java implementation gives me this number ```123000004117574260000000000000.00000000000000000```.

Comment: So, I wanted to say that looks the tail of numbers (822262431744) is something which is not exists in real float.

Comment: Anything after about here `123000004` does not exist in a `float`. All you can expect from a `float` is between 7 and 9 digits. Have a read of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: For me it does not seem right. As I've mentioned before, I splitted float to mantissa and fractions, and build the decimal number in Java. It was exact what java format gives me. The same number. And these leading zeros (before the dot) it case when you pass through 23 fractions and take the sum by 2^30.

Comment: I see that you are trying to explain me how floating point numbers are maden. But I think the point is far from here. The question is how it transforms float to string with such precision? Does these numbers are fractions 1/2^(23 + ...)?

Comment: The IEEE 754 `float` nearest to 0.123e30 *is* 123000004117574256822262431744.

Comment: But actually the 0.123e30 represents everything halfway between prev(0.123e30) and 0.123e30 and halfway between 0.123e30 and next(0.123e30). Java might just be better at picking a nicer decimal number within that range than C. In C the float will be passed as double on common CPUs with variadic args so the C double-to-string function might not have a choice about adding more digits. The double has a more precision even if that is purely invented by the conversion from float.

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that the Java result is not representable as an IEEE 754 float either, which seems broken to me.

Comment: @molbdnilo how did you get this value? So, my point is how build such number from a float value?

Comment: @ValeraDubrava read up on how floating point numbers are stored in IEEE 754 format. Then have a read of [Exploring Binary on Floating Point](https://www.exploringbinary.com/tag/floating-point/)

Comment: @RichardCritten, sorry but I do not get it - how does this thread helps me?

Comment: @ValeraDubrava there have been many bugs in the language support libraries (C, Java etc) when converting floating point numbers to strings and in the other direction.  The linked blog documents come of them and the other issues.  These issues can explain why there are differences between the behaviour of different languages when representing floating point as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found out what the difference between Java float -> decimal -> string conversion and c++ float -> string (decimal) conversion. I did not find the original source code, but I replicated the same code in Java to make it clear. I think the code explains everything:

```java
    // the context size might be calculated properly by getting maximum 
    // float number (including exponent value) - its 40 + scale, 17 for me
    MathContext context = new MathContext(57, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal divisor = BigDecimal.valueOf(2);
    int tmp = Float.floatToRawIntBits(1.23e30f)
    boolean sign = tmp < 0;
    tmp <<= 1;
    // there might be NaN value, this code does not support it
    int exponent = (tmp >>> 24) - 127;
    tmp <<= 8;
    int mask = 1 << 23;
    int fraction = mask | (tmp >>> 9);
    // at this line we have all parts of the float: sign, exponent and fractions. Let's build mantissa
    BigDecimal mantissa = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i ++) {
        if ((fraction & mask) == mask) {
            // i'm not sure about speed, maybe division at each iteration might be faster than pow
            mantissa = mantissa.add(divisor.pow(-i, context));
        }
        mask >>>= 1;
    }

    // it was the core line where I was losing accuracy, because of context
    BigDecimal decimal = mantissa.multiply(divisor.pow(exponent, context), context);
    String str = decimal.setScale(17, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toPlainString();
    // add minus manually, because java lost it if after the scale value become 0, C++ version of code doesn't do it
    if (sign) {
        str = "-" + str;
    }
    return str;
```

Maybe topic is useless. Who really need to have the same implementation like C++ has? But at least this code keeps all precision for float number comparing to the most popular way converting float to decimal string:

```java
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(1.23e30f).setScale(17, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toPlainString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read documentation:

[printf, fprintf, sprintf, snprintf, printf_s, fprintf_s, sprintf_s, snprintf_s - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

> The **format** string consists of ordinary multibyte characters (except `%`), which are copied unchanged into the output stream, and conversion specifications. Each conversion specification has the following format:
>
> - introductory `%` character
> - ...
> - (optional) `.` followed by integer number or `*`, or neither that specifies *precision* of the conversion. In the case when `*` is used, the *precision* is specified by an additional argument of type int, which appears before the argument to be converted, but after the argument supplying minimum field width if one is supplied. If the value of this argument is negative, it is ignored. If neither a number nor `*` is used, the precision is taken as zero. See the table below for exact effects of *precision*.
>
> ....
>
> | Conversion Specifier | Explanation | Expected Argument Type |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `f` `F` | converts **floating-point number** to the decimal notation in the style *[-]ddd.ddd*. *Precision* specifies the exact number of digits to appear after the decimal point character. The default precision is 6. In the *alternative implementation* decimal point character is written even if no digits follow it. For infinity and not-a-number conversion style see notes. | double |

So with `f` you forced form `ddd.ddd` (no exponent) and with `.17` you have forced to show 17 digits after decimal separator. With such big value printed outcome looks that odd.

Answer (score -1):

The C++ implementation you are using uses the IEEE-754 binary32 format for `float`. In this format, the closet representable value to 0.123•10<sup>30</sup> is 123,000,004,117,574,256,822,262,431,744, which is represented in the binary32 format as +13,023,132•2<sup>73</sup>. So `0.123e30f` in the source code yields the number 123,000,004,117,574,256,822,262,431,744. (Because the number is represented as +13,023,132•2<sup>73</sup>, we know its value is that exactly, which is 123,000,004,117,574,256,822,262,431,744, even though the digits “123000004117574256822262431744” are not stored directly.)

Then, when you format it with `%.17f`, your C++ implementation prints the exact value faithfully, yielding “123000004117574256822262431744.00000000000000000”. This accuracy is not required by the C++ standard, and some C++ implementations will not do the conversion exactly.

The Java specification also does not require formatting of floating-point values to be exact, at least in some formatting operations. (I am going from memory and some supposition here; I do not have a citation at hand.) It allows, perhaps even requires, that only a certain number of correct digits be produced, after which zeros are used if needed for positioning relative to the decimal point or for the requested format.

> The number has much higher precision than float can be.

For any value represented in the `float` format, that value has infinite precision. The number +13,023,132•2<sup>73</sup> is **exactly** +13,023,132•2<sup>73</sup>, which is exactly 123,000,004,117,574,256,822,262,431,744, to infinite precision. The precision the format has for representing numbers affects only **which** numbers it can represent, not how precisely it represents the numbers that it does represent.

Comment: `binary32` representation of 123,000,004,117,574,256,822,262,431,744 is 1.552478313446045×2⁹⁶ and that corresponds with reality https://godbolt.org/z/39q8Eo1MM

Your claim that the same number is represented in `binary32` as +13,023,132×2⁷³ has no basis in reality. The standards merely don't prohibit other formats.

Comment: Here is an up-to-date overview of IEEE 754 formats from Nvidia https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/floating-point/index.html#formats

Comment: IEEE 754-2019 clause 3.3 says we may treat the significand as an integer: “to view the significand as an integer… floating-point numbers of the form (-1)^s×b^q×c, where… c is a number represented by a digit string of the form d_0 d_1 d_2… d_(p-1) where d_i is an integer digit 0≤d_i<b (c is therefore an integer with 0≤c≤b^p).” (See original for full text and formatting; it is not feasible to reproduce here.) Neither GNU’s `ieee754.h` nor any Nvidia documents supersede this.

Comment: You are confusing _view_ with _binary representation_.

Comment: No, I am not. See the full text of the cited passage.